# Figures showing at the end of the document in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I have been working on this issue since yesterday and have checked almost all the solutions but I'm still not able to solve this issue. All the figures and tables I put in the document shows at the end of the document instead of where I place them.

```
fig_cap           : yes
keep_tex          : yes
floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no


documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
header-includes:
 \usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
```

I have added `float` package as well as `fig_cap` in yaml above as recommended in some other solutions. Also I have globally defined `fig.pos = H`

````
```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')
```
````

This is the histogram I'm trying to showin between my paragraphs (it moves down to the end of document as soon as I use fig.cap)

````
```{r Histogram, out.width = "90%", out.height = "100%", fig.align = "center", fig.pos='H', out.extra = '',fig.cap= "eee", echo=FALSE}
histogram_plot <- ggplot(dataset1, aes(x=SocialNetworkUse))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 30) +
  labs(x="Social Network Use (Hours)", y = "Respondents")
  histogram_plot
```
````

Now this is the what I'm getting in my tex file

```
\begin{figure}[H]

{\centering \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,height=1\textheight,]{ANLY-699_files/figure-latex/Histogram-1} 

}

\caption{eee}\label{fig:Histogram}
\end{figure}
```

However the fff files shows this output

```
\begin{figure*}[hbt]
\ifnextchar[{\eatarg}{}
[H]

    {\centering \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth,]{ANLY-699_files/figure-latex/Histogram-1}
    
    }
    
    \caption{foff}\label{fig:Histogram}
    \end{figure*}
```

Fairly new to Rmarkdown and not sure what's causing the figures to not stay in place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] which we can copy&paste to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Off-topic: you should not specify both the width and the height of your image, this will is basically all cases result in a distorted image

Comment: When using your YAML my example plot stays at the exact position between two paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add   `figsintext : yes` in my Yaml file to solve the issue.